# Carregar controller com hífen ou underline na URL - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rotas

Eu hospedei meu projeto feito no CodeIgniter 3 em um servidor usando Linux e PHP 7 e não consigo carregar certos links, dá erro 404.

Exemplo de Nome do Controller: `Relatorio_Detalhado.php`

Link na url:

```
http://127.0.0.1/projeto/index.php/relatorio-detalhado/index ou 
http://127.0.0.1/projeto/index.php/relatorio_detalhado/index
```

Obs.: O projeto local na minha máquina funciona normalmente, agora quando jogo na hospedagem, me retorna o erro 404.

Comment: Qual a versão do codeigniter local? E do PHP?

Comment: Como esta o nome da classe Relatorio_Detalhado.php ?

Comment: Já tentou nomear o *controller* como `Relatorio_detalhado`, com o `d` minúsculo?

Comment: Obrigado a todos, só renomeei o controller para Relatorio_detalhado e funcionou, valeuu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque o nome do arquivo para Relatorio_**d**etalhado.php

assim como na class

```
class Relatorio_detalhado extends CI_Controller
```